# Issue with Centering an Element Inside of an Anchor Element Using Flexbox and Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm facing an issue with centering an `<a>` element inside of an other anchor element using flexbox and absolute positioning. Initially, I had a `<div>` container with an image inside of it, and I centered a button within it using the following SCSS and HTML code:

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="/assets/img/gallery-image-1.png">
    <a class="image__zoom-button">
        <img src="/assets/svg/magnify.svg" alt="Magnify Icon">
    </a>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.image {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

        img {
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
        }
}

.image__zoom-button {
    background-color: $white-09;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This way, it worked and centered the `.image__zoom-button` inside, but when I use an anchor tag instead of div, then it won't be on the center:

HTML:

```
<a class="image">
    <img src="/assets/img/gallery-image-1.png">
    <a class="image__zoom-button">
        <img src="/assets/svg/magnify.svg" alt="Magnify Icon">
    </a>
</a>
```

Also, when instead of flexbox, I use `top: 0; right: 0;` etc., then the element is not relative to the `.image` container, but the container outside of that, even though `.image` has a `position: relative` property.

How can I fix this, so when I use `<a>` instead of `<div>`, the button inside of it is centered?

Note that the `img` element has to be separate from its container, it can't be a background, it has to be an `img` element.

Comment: It's invalid in HTML to nest an anchor inside an anchor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that having an anchor () inside another anchor () is not valid HTML, and it can cause unexpected behavior in browsers. If you want to create clickable areas within a larger clickable area, consider using another approach like the map and area tags. But if your goal is to only replace the  with an . The most likely reason the button is not centered after replacing the  with an  is due to some browser default styles on the anchor tag, which may interfere with flexbox positioning. The solution would be to explicitly set the box-sizing, width, and height on the .image class, and ensure that the default styles for the anchor tag are reset

```css
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    //your styles
}
```

Ensure the .image__zoom-button has absolute positioning

```css
.image__zoom-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    // other styles
}
```